# Applying the Lambert W function for a new equation

Tags: functions, special-functions

I am a physical chemist, and we are trying to model a simple process.  We ended up arriving at the following equation.

\begin{align}
ax^{-7/2}e^{-bx(ln(cx)-1)}=1
\end{align}

We'd like to solve for $x$.  All constants ($a$, $b$, $c$) are real, positive. a is on the order of 31 and b and c are on the order of the -3. I have found the following relationship from the following: (Edwards, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.08910.pdf)

\begin{align}
y=ax^be^{cx^d}+f
\end{align}

Can be inverted into

\begin{align}
x=\left[\frac{b}{cd} W\left(\frac{cd(y-f)^{\frac{d}{b}}}{ba^{\frac{d}{b}}}\right)\right]^{1/d}
\end{align}
Where W is the Lambert W function.

But obviously I have a $\ln(x)$ in the exponential function. We'd love to find a good expression for x, either exact, or approximate through expansion.  We can check it against a numerical solution.

Any ideas?  Thanks all!

Comment: Can you give typical values for $a,b,c$?

Comment: I assume the constants are reals. Are they all positive? Is $b$ an integer?

Comment: a, b and c are all reals and positive.  a is on the order of 10^31.  b is and c are small, 2-3 ish.

Comment: This can't be right. Did you mean $10^3$ perhaps? That still looks weird, constants are expected to be of the same order of magnitude.

Comment: Sorry, this is a unit thing.  It can be of order 1.

Comment: $e^{a\ln(b)}=(e^{\ln(b)})^a = b^a$. Are you sure that the expression is typed correctly? Because if so this is just a polynomial.

Comment: @StellaBiderman ... true, it is $b^a$, but if $a$ is not an integer, then this is not a polynomial.

Comment: I know someone who works with @JRChemistry and have updated the equation per her correction. JR, if you can confirm that the updated equation is correct that would be great.

Comment: $e^{x\ln(x)} = x^x$, so this whole equation can be rewritten as $ax^{-7/2}(cx)^{bx}e^{-bx} = 1$ or (by combining bases) $ax^{bx-\frac{7}{2}}\left(\frac{c}{e}\right)^{bx}=1$.

Comment: Thank you.  Is that solvable?  Are there any special functions that can get there?